# How to create multi auth in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I used to be for laravel 5.5 and earlier than https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth .

But this repository don't update for laravel 7.0

How to create multi auth in Laravel 7.0 ?

Comment: Try this [package](https://github.com/bitfumes/laravel-multiauth) which support laravel 7 too

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a package the you can use this package [laravel-multiauth](https://github.com/bitfumes/laravel-multiauth)

**OR**

if you want to create custom `multi-auth` based on a field in your users table for.e.g `is_admin` then follow the below steps:

Assuming you have installed Laravel and made a connection to database

**Step1:** Add new row `is_admin` in users table and model. then run the migration.

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email');
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->boolean('is_admin')->nullable(); // add this
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();

        });

}
```

**app/User.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'is_admin' //add here
];
```

Then run the migration

```
   php artisan migrate
```

**Step2:**  Create `Auth` using scaffold

Install `laravel/ui` package using below command

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

**Generate auth**

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth 

npm install

npm run dev
```

**Step3:**  Create `IsAdmin` Middleware will allows only `admin` access users to that routes

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

> app/Http/middleware/IsAdmin.php

Add this in `IsAdmin` middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->user()->is_admin == 1){
       return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect(‘home’)->with(‘error’,"You don't have admin access.");
}
```

Register your `IsAdmin` middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
       'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
       'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
       'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
   'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'is_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class, // add this

];
```

**Step4:**  Create your route for admin in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('admin/home', 'HomeController@adminHome')->name('admin.home')->middleware('is_admin');
```

**Step5:** Add `adminHome()` method for admin route in `app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php`

```
public function adminHome()
 {
      return view('adminHome');
 }
```

**Step6:** Change `LoginController`, when user will login than we redirect according to user access. if normal user than we will redirect to home route and if admin user than we redirect to admin route in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{   
    $input = $request->all();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
    {
        if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.home');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login')
            ->with('error','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
    }

}
```